# Intuition behind $R$ is a field $\iff$ only ideals are $R$ and $0$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, ideals, intuition, normal-subgroups

There are two well-known facts in algebra:

- Every subgroup of an abelian subgroup is a normal subgroup.
- Given a commutative ring $R$, one has that $R$ is a field if and only if its only ideals are $R$ and $0$.

Many textbooks often describe an ideal of a ring as the analog to a normal subgroup of a group. It is also reasonable to regard commutative rings as an analog to abelian groups. Yet, intuitively these two facts above are complete opposite of each other. What's the intuition behind such a drastic difference?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The analogy is that both normal subgroups and ideals allow us to define quotient groups/rings, and both are kernels of homomorphisms of groups/rings. But other than that, they are not the same thing. An ideal is usually not even a subring, since a proper ideal never contains the identity. And I'm not sure why commutative rings should be analogous to abelian groups. They have different axioms.

Comment: I don't see how they are opposite. The analogue of fields for the group setting would be simple groups $G$, where the only normal subgroups are $0$ and $G$. Just like fields are very special rings with only trivial ideals, simple groups are very special groups with trivial subgroups. (Of course simple abelian groups are just cyclic of prime order, they are *much* less interesting than fields.)

Comment: @CaptainLama I didn't think of it from this direction. Is there any reason why such an analogy should hold other than mere coincidence?

Comment: If $R$ is a field, every module over $R$ is free, and isomorphic to $R^n$ if the module is finitely generated. If $i$ were nonzero, $R/I$ would be a strange vector space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two facts that justify saying that "normal subgroups are to groups" as "ideals are to rings", but that's just about all we can say.

(1) Normal subgroups are precisely the kernels of group morphisms.

(1') Ideals are precisely the kernels of ring morphisms.

(2) Normal subgroups are the only subsets on which the natural group structure on the cosets is well-defined.

(2') Ideals are the only subsets on which the naturall ring structure on the cosets is well-defined.

In short, both are the only objects that allow us to look at quotient structures.